# Get minimum and maximum time value from list of object property using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have settings object with property

```
class Settings
{
    DateTime StartTime;
    DateTime EndTime;
}
```

and I have created a list of this setting object.

How can I get the MaxTime and MinTime from the collection of objects using LINQ?

Answer (score 10):

```
var minStartTime = settings.Min(setting => setting.StartTime);    // returns 8am
var maxEndTime = settings.Max(setting => setting.EndTime);        // returns 5pm
```

This returns the lowest and highest times.  Other answers are telling you how to get the difference between max and min, which does not appear to be what you asked for.

Comment: @Pramod - if this is the answer you want then click the little tick mark next to the current number of votes the question has...

Comment: +1 for correct interpretation of the question and not typing what you expect the OP means.

Comment: I see 4 different comments about how to accept an answer .... and no accepted answer.  Oh well never mind, next question please!

Comment: @Bazzz: JK also guessed as to what the OP meant -- it just happens that his interpretation was what the OP wanted, and mine was not.  Interpretation *is* "typing what you expect the OP means"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a minimum and maximum of the time deltas:

```
Settings[] settings = ...;

var max = settings.Max(s => s.EndTime - s.StartTime);
var min = settings.Min(s => s.EndTime - s.StartTime);
```

Comment: obj1.StartTime=8AM, obj1.EndTime=5PM,

Comment: @PramodChoudhari: Not quite sure what you're trying to say, but with those values the difference between them (EndTime - StartTime) would be a TimeSpan structure with the Hours property set to 9. See the [`-` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx) for DateTimes.

Comment: -1 OP just asked for the max and min values not the difference between the two.

Comment: @JK: OP asked for min and max across an object with two fields -- what he meant was subject to interpretation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
var max = (from item in myList
      select item.StartTime - item.EndTime).Max()

var min = (from item in myList
      select item.StartTime - item.EndTime).Min()
```